# Backup Window 10 to a folder of external drive

Tags: windows-10, backup, windows-backup

I have a C drive (SSD 1 TB) Installed with Windows 10 and an external D drive (HDD 8TB). I want to manually back up my whole C drive to a folder of D (The folder name might simply be the timestamp when I do the backup).    Because I have other computers that will use this backup. Other computers have a variable C drive size (Might not be one terabyte).  When in need I want to replace those drives (any size) with some folder of the D drive So I could use the exact version when I want to.  How to achieve this and what software should I use?

Answer (score 0):

What you likely need is not a *backup* of the C: drive (i.e., copying files), but a complete disk image (copying *everything* on the disk, including hidden files, and all partitions). There are many reputable tools to make a disk image, such as [Macrium Reflect](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree), [AOMEI Backupper](https://www.aomeitech.com/aomei-backupper.html?AFFILIATE=6732&__c=1) and [alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/macrium-reflect/?platform=windows). Copying one file at a time is *exceedingly* slow compared to direct disk I/O used by these applications, and prone to failure.

That image can be accessed on other PC's using the same software, so all data is available. However, if you wish to use *applications* from the image, *some* might not work unless installed on the other PC.

**If** the PC's are *identical*, it might be possible restore an image to that PC's drive, and to boot from it (clone a drive), but if there are any differences in PC's, additional drivers might be needed. Also, there are licensing issues that might prevent Windows OS or software from being activated.